# Implementing reselect in redux prevents new changes to appear instantly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, frontend, reselect

In my React project, I have implemented memoization using reselect library.
The state basically has a list of objects which I render as cards.

Before implementing reselect, whenever I added a new element, the change instantly showed up and a new card got added at the end. However, now when I add a new element it does not instantly shows up, but rather shows up when the page is reloaded.

Why does this happen? And is there a way to fix this without removing the use of reselect library

EDIT : The issue has been solved, and as pointed out in the answers it was because I was simply mutating the state

The earlier code was as follows

```
case IssueActionTypes.ADD_ISSUE:
        state.issueList.push(action.payload)
        return {
            ...state
        }
```

which I replaced with

```
case IssueActionTypes.ADD_ISSUE:
        return {
            ...state,
            issueList : [...state.issueList, action.payload]
        }
```

which fixed the issue

Comment: Yes! You were modifying the state instead of returning a new modified state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are returning mutated state in your reducers instead of returning a new array.

[Docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-why-isnt-my-selector-recomputing-when-the-input-state-changes):

> createSelector uses an identity check (===) to detect that an input
> has changed, so mutating an existing object will not trigger the
> selector to recompute because mutating an object does not change its
> identity. Note that if you are using Redux, mutating the state object
> is almost certainly a mistake.

Example of returning mutated state (from docs):

> ```
> export default function todos(state = initialState, action) {
>   switch (action.type) {
>   case COMPLETE_ALL:
>     const areAllMarked = state.every(todo => todo.completed)
>     // BAD: mutating an existing object
>     return state.map(todo => {
>       todo.completed = !areAllMarked
>       return todo
>     })
>
>   default:
>     return state
>   }
> }
> ```